# Exclude username or password from UserChangeForm in Django Auth

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication, django-users

I'm trying to figure out a way on how to exclude the username and/or password from the `UserChangeForm`. I tried both `exclude` and `fields` but I doesn't work for these two fields.

Here's some code:

```
class ArtistForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Artist
        exclude = ('user',)

class UserForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            )
        exclude = ('username','password',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        artist_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            self.artist = kwargs['instance'].artist
            artist_kwargs['instance'] = self.artist
        self.artist_form = ArtistForm(*args, **artist_kwargs)
        self.fields.update(self.artist_form.fields)
        self.initial.update(self.artist_form.initial)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(UserForm, self).clean()
        self.errors.update(self.artist_form.errors)
        return cleaned_data

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.artist_form.save(commit)
        return super(UserForm, self).save(commit)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For Django v2 just set password to None.

```
class UserForm(UserChangeForm):
    password = None

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            )
```

Comment: It's working. But why i explicitly need to tell password = None ? As i don't include password in the fields.

Comment: That's because `UserChangeForm` does include password field, so you need to override it.

Comment: Saved my day. Very useful hint.

Comment: This was very helpful! I would upvote this twice if I could. Btw this still works in version 4.0.3

Answer (score 11):

You won't be able to do this if you use `UserChangeForm`.

See this https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py.

You will notice that `UserChangeForm` on this page explicitly defines `username` and `password`. These fields are present in variable `declared_fields` on the form.

`exclude` and `fields` only work on fields which are taken from `model` defined in `Meta`. If you explicitly define some field i.e `declared_fields`, they will be present on the form even if they have been excluded using `exclude`. So, these fields show for you.

To read more on this check `__new__` of `ModelFormMetaclass` at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py

Workaround:

Do not use UserChangeForm and read its code. It doesn't provide you much. You can write your own form which only extends from `ModelForm` and set `Meta Model` as user. Copy the parts from `UserChangeForm` in your form.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #copy any functionality you want form UserChangeForm

    def clean_password(self):
        #copy functionality provided by UserChangeForm
```

Comment: Ok that did the job, but now username and password get NULLed every time I call on `save()`. Plus the argument from my extended user class don't get saved ether.

Answer (score 1):

i think it may help you ...

while iterating over form field in template,write

```
if for field in UserChangeFormObject:
    {% ifnotequal field.lable password %}
        #process your form field here
    {% endifnotequal%}
```

Read more here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.2/